# React Table dynamic columns and rows from Json Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So here is my question. How can I display the header names and its respective rows dynamically? I am using a simple react table right now.

I have hardcoded the names as you can see in the table (2017-8, 2017-9, .....) from the image.

the columns should be label and rows should be its respective value from the referencePoints array.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just place a code block in the table header as follows:

```
<th>{header}</th>
```

You can receive your header from props or state in the render method. If you are receiving it from Redux your render method might contain:

```
const {header} = this.props;

return(
   <table>
   <tr> <th>{header}</th>...</tr>
   ...
   </table>
)
```

You might also loop through your headers if you want:

```
<tr> {headers.map((head, i)=>(<th key={i}>{head}</th>))} </tr>
```

Make sure to add a key to items added with an array. React will warn you if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a loop across your table headers like

```
header = [];
Dates.forEach(date => {
header.push(<td>{date.value}</td>
});
```

you can render like

```
<th>
{header}
<th>
```

The code is just a representation and not actual code